# Can't figure out why $wpdb is not working in wordpress page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

ok I have considerably good knowledge in computer languages and architecture but I am really novice in wordpress. I am trying to read data from a custom table (MySQL) of wordpress database but not sure why $wpdb variable is not working.
Following is my code which is written directly in wordpress page (editor)

```
<?php

   global $wpdb;
   $wpdb->show_errors();

   $sqlQuery = "select ev.id, ev.entry_id, ev.slug, ev.value
                from wp_cf_form_entry_values as ev, wp_cf_form_entries as e
                where e.id = ev.entry_id and e.form_id = 'CF5928820181223'";

  $results = $wpdb->get_results($sqlQuery);
  $wpdb->print_error();
?>
```

When I am running page I am getting the following output (it is not output but printed in the page)

```
show_errors();

   $sqlQuery = “select ev.id, ev.entry_id, ev.slug, ev.value
               from wp_cf_form_entry_values as ev, wp_cf_form_entries as e
               where e.id = ev.entry_id and e.form_id = ‘CF5928820181223′”;

   $results = $wpdb->get_results($sqlQuery);
   $wpdb->print_error();
?>
```

It seems to me that $wpdb object is not being instantiated. I will greatly appreciate if anyone can give a pointer where I am missing things.

Comment: What is the error text?

Answer (score 1):

SQL query using WPDB will not work if you write query in Page editor in back-end. You should write code in your page template file. i.e. page.php in your theme.

You can ask me for any other confusions!